# p:datatable filter does not work right anymore after update 7.0 to 8.0

Tags: datatable, primefaces, filterfunction, primefaces-7.0, primefaces-8.0

I have a datatable with multiple filter for filtering in backend. In Primefaces 7.0 it all works out fine but after the update to 8.0 all filter seem to use the last defined filter in the xhtml side.

All cloumns looks like this just with different method in filteredfunction:

```
        <p:column filterBy="#{variant}" headerText="source"
                  filterFunction="#{variantBean.filterBySource}"
                  style="padding-top: 7px;">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="menu2" value="#{variantBean.selectedSources}" label="Select many"
                                      filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
                                      onchange="PF('dataTable').filter()" multiple="true">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{variantBean.sourceList}" var="externalSource"
                                   itemValue="#{externalSource.toString()}"/>
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{variantBean.getExternalSources(variant)}"/>
        </p:column>
```

For example if i have 3 colums with the filterFunction value variantBean.filterby1, variantBean.filterby2 and variantBean.filterby3 not matter which i use. In backend it always go in filterBy3 but with filter = null.

```
 public boolean filterBy3 (Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
...
}
```

I dont know what i have to change to make it run in 8.0 like in 7.0 before. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried reading the  PF migration notes? Compared with the showcase? Etc...

Comment: I used the migration guide to check my application (https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide ).
If i understand everything right nothing should impact my datatables. 
I also checked the showcase (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml ) but it does not match my use case with the selectCheckboxMenu.
I'am actually try to find out if onchange="PF('dataTable').filter()" trigger another method now compared to 7.0 but have not find anything helpfull yet.

Comment: If you did all this before me asking, that is good, but please mention those things then, we are not clairvoiyant and the first impression we get then is of a not too good question)  Still an [mcve] is als relevant so someone can try to reproduce if they have the time... Cheres

Comment: Is variant the var of your datatable?